# After upgrading Android Studio to 4.0 I get 'Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected non-class file'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I try to Run an Instrumentation test with Android Studio 4.0 I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected non-class file: META-INF\versions\9\org\junit\platform\commons\util\ModuleUtils$ModuleReferenceScanner.class
```

It did not happen until I upgraded Android Studio from 3.x to 4.0.

Anyone solved it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the end, It wasn't related with Android Studio upgrade at all. If a comment line ```apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf' ```in build.gradle it works.

Comment: did you fix this issue?

Comment: Commenting the line mentioned above fixed the issue but this disables temporary firebase performance monitoring so I can't consider this a valid solution. If plugin is updated I'll try to upgrade it and Run tests again. In case it works, I will post it here and mark it as valid solution.

Comment: do you use JUnit5 for tests? Maybe this is the reason

Comment: I'm using JUnit5 libraries but running as JUnit4 (vintage). All instrumentation tests are annotated with `@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)`

Comment: Did you figure out how to fix?
I've the same problem because of the firebase-perf

Comment: No. For now, I've disabled firebase-pref until someone finds a solution.

Comment: @Chave I've reported the issue to the Firebase team. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1888#issuecomment-675041242

Answer (score -1):

This is the hack I came up with to solve the problem... I don't think these class files are needed, and deleting them doesn't seem to cause any problems.

```
/**
 * Hack to work around this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62540396
 * I don't think we use these class files at all so we can just delete them before dexing. I tried to see if we could
 * configure the file collection to exclude them instead, but it's actually just a collection of folders, which
 * internally the task just traverses separately.
 */
allprojects {
    tasks.withType<DexArchiveBuilderTask> {
        doFirst {
            mixedScopeClasses
                .asFileTree
                .matching { include("**/META-INF/versions/9/**/*.class") }
                .forEach { it.delete() }
        }
    }
}
```

(This is Kotlin - if you use Groovy it will be slightly different)

Comment: How you access to DexArchiveBuilderTask? It's an internal task

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that the task is in a package named `internal`? That doesn't matter, since the class itself is public. You should be able to import `com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexArchiveBuilderTask`. Does that work for you?